# Do Vedas describe about Rudra riding on a black chariot driven by red horses, about wearing golden jewellery and holding pinaka bow and deadly arrows?

Tags: vedas, shiva, vedic-gods

I have read or found that he is also mentioned as the lord of thieves and robbers (taskaranaam pati), wears golden jewellery, rides on chariot & carries deadly weapon. He was also considered as a good physician or surgeon. Please describe about it briefly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes , In Vedas Lord Rudra is described as riding on chariot driven by brown horses , wearing golden jewellery and holding a bow and deadly arrows. The one thing which has to be taken in considaration though is that "Pinaka" the name of Lord Rudras bow as you have enquired is not found in vedas.  Let us now see how he is described in Rig-Veda and Atharva-Veda.  In [**Rig-Veda  Mandala 2 - Sukta 33**](https://archive.org/details/RigVedaSanhitaByHHWilsonVol2/page/n205) we  mainly find the description the see of the sukta is Rishi Grisamada.

## Lord Rudra holding bow and arrows and wearing golden colored jewellery.

> सथिरेभिरङगैः पुरुरूप उग्रो बभ्रुः शुक्रेभिः पिपिशेहिरण्यैः | 
> ईशानादस्य भुवनस्य भूरेर्न वा उ योषद रुद्रादसुर्यम || 
> अर्हन्बिभर्षि सायकानि धन्वार्हन्निष्कं यजतं विश्वरूपम | 
> अर्हन्निदं दयसे विश्वमभ्वं न वा ओजीयो रुद्र त्वदस्ति || RV 2.33.10
> ||
>
> 9 (Firm) with strong limbs , assuming many forms ,fierce ,and
> tawny-coloured , **he shines with brillient golden ornaments** .
> Vigour is inseparable from Rudra , the supreme ruler and lord of this
> universe. 10 Worthy(of reverence), **thou   bearest arrow and a bow**
> , worthy(of praise ) thou wearest an adorable and omniform
> **necklace**; worthy ( of adoration ) thou preservest all this vast universe ; there is no    one more powerful than thou.

---

## Rudra's Chariot

Lord Rudra is also mentioned as driving a chariot drawn by brown horses and he is unlike Rig-Veda described with black complexion  in [**Atharva-Veda 11.2 -Rudra Sukta**](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/av/av11002.htm) .This sukta is dedicated to Bhava, Sarva and Rudra. The name Rudra is also used both as a name of Shiva, synonymous with Bhava, Sarva, Ugra and Mahadeva.

> श्वावाश्वं कृष्णमसितं मृणन्तं भीमं रथं केशिन: पादयन्तं |
>  पूर्वे
> प्रतीमो नमो अस्त्वस्मै | AV 11.2 18 ||
>
> Foremost we go to meet his car, **the chariot of the long-haired God,
> Drawn by brown horses,** dusky, black, o'erthrowing, slaying, terrible.
> Let reverence be paid to him

---

## Rudra as physician .

Rudra's healing powers are often praised by Rgvedic seers. He is mentioned as the chief physician amongst physicians.The medicaments of Rudra are the said to ease the pain of disease and defence against danger.

> मा त्वा रुद्र चुक्रुधामा नमोभिर्मा दुष्टुती वृषभ मा सहूती | 
>  उन नो
> वीरानर्पय भेषजेभिर्भिषक्तमं तवा भिषजां शर्णोमि || [**RV .II.33.4**](https://archive.org/details/RigVedaSanhitaByHHWilsonVol2/page/n205) || 
> I hear that thou art a chief physician amongst physicians. (Wilson) .
> I hear thee famed as best of all physicians. (Griffith)

Comment: In case of chariot and horses color Griffith thinks that black is the color of horses . The dusky black color is also mentioned , so the verses are not much clear here and there are various views on this. I will try to find more regarding this in time.